# Reconstructing 2d image from 1d pixel sequence

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, signal-processing

Imagine there's an image of size n by m. Then it's flattened into a list of pixels with length of n*m. How to restore original image if n and m are unknown?

The idea is not to find all pairs of divisors of length, but to find some metric which is highest then sampling width is closest to original width of an image. Simular to adjusting horizontal hold on old analog TV.

I'm sure there is an algorithm which is supposed to do this exact thing but I couldn't find it.

Comment: Do you look for an efficient solution ? You could check what the FFT of the sequence looks like ..

Answer (score 2):

Bruteforcing it appears to work.

I try all combinations `(h, w)` where `n` is the number of pixels, and `h` and `w` are divisors such that `n == h * w`.

I return the pair of divisors that minimise the average difference between the value of a pixel on a row with the corresponding pixel on the next row.

Note that the value of a pixel is a triplet representing the three colours. I did not even try to be smart about what "difference between two colours" might mean. I just subtracted red from red, green from green, blue from blue, and summed it all with `.mean()` because I was too lazy to do a sum of squares or anything smart.

On an example picture of a bear, it works.

```py
from imageio.v3 import imread
from sympy import divisors
import numpy as np

img = np.array(imread('Downloads/bear.png'))
height, width, n_channels = img.shape # (90, 136, 3)
flatimg = img.reshape((height*width, n_channels)) # (12240, 3)

def find_dims(flatimg):
    n_pixels, n_channels = flatimg.shape # (12240, 3)
    divs = divisors(n_pixels)[1:-1]
    height,width = min(
        ((height, width) for height, width in zip(divs, reversed(divs))),
        key=lambda dim: np.diff(flatimg.reshape((*dim,n_channels)), axis=0).mean()
    )
    return height, width

print(find_dims(flatimg))
# (90, 136)
```

[image: bear 80x153]80x153  [image: bear 85x144]85x144  [image: bear 90x136]90x136

[image: bear 102x120]102x120  [image: bear 120x102]120x102  [image: bear 136x90]136x90

Answer (score 2):

Try the divisors of the image area, with reasonable ratios (if the image wasn't cropped, the ratio should not exceed 16:9.

For the different combinations, compute the sum of the vertical gradient magnitude across the whole image. It should be minimum for the right choice.

Comment: That's exactly what I did in my answer, except I used mean rather than sum and did not worry about the ratios being reasonable.

Comment: @Stef: is the difference of the scores significant ?

Comment: On my 90x136 pixels bear image: with `.mean()`, the scores vary from 121.36 to 136.22 and the minimum corresponds to the correct dimensions even when trying all ratios. With `.sum()` instead, the scores vary from 2501057 to 4784915 and it becomes important to worry about reasonable ratios, because the minimum corresponds to unreasonable dimensions 2x6120, presumably simply because the sum has a lot fewer terms with this ratio.

Comment: @Stef: there should be no difference between the results with the sum and with the mean, as they are proportional. The variation range of the mean seems dangerously narrow.

Comment: They're only about proportional if the ratios don't change too much. The number of terms in the sum is not exactly constant, since `a.diff(axis=0)` on an array of shape (h, w) returns an array of shape (h-1, w). Here, `h*w` is constant equal to the number of pixels, but `(h-1)*w = h*w - w` is not constant.

Comment: @Stef: if h-1 significantly differs from h (?), the sum should be corrected by a factor h/(h-1), or a line be duplicated.

Comment: Yes, or just using mean instead of sum.

Comment: @Stef You could use [`np.gradient()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.gradient.html) (which preserves the size of the input), instead of `np.diff()` (which does not) so that `np.sum()` and `np.mean()` differ only by a constant scaling.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at `raw2tiff.c` in the `tools` directory of `libtiff` it seeks to around the middle of a raw image file and guesses different scanline widths and reads pairs of lines till the correlation between the two is maximised and uses that as the width. I assume the theory is that most scanlines in a photo are pretty similar, i.e. highly correlated with each other.